# git alias to clean/reset all repositories in a directory

Tags: git, bash

I want to clean/reset all git repositories in a directory recursively.

If I execute the following command it works as expected:

```
find . -name .git -type d -execdir sh -c "git clean -xdf" \;
```

I have problems converting the command to a git alias:

```
xxx = "!f() { find . -name .git -type d -execdir sh -c "git clean -xdf" ; ; }; f; "
```

I have tried to fix the errors such as `syntax error near unexpected token`;'` however I am going in a circle with no success.

Please help me to create the alias. 10x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
xxx = "!f() { find . -name .git -type d -execdir git clean -xdf \\; ; }; f"
```

A few things:

- No need to wrap the command in `sh -c`, you can use it directly
- You need to escape the `\` in `\;` at the end of the `find` command, writing as: `\\;`